# Как преобразовать тип полученного сообщения от сервера в String?

Tags: javascript

Принимаю сообщение от сервера, нужно вывести то, что отправляет сервер.

```
socket.onmessage = function(msg)
{
alert(msg);
}
```

Сервер отправляет:

```
ws.send("Welcome!");
```

В итоге в alert'e всплывает такой текст: [object MessageEvent]

Comment: `alert(msg.data)`

Comment: Используй для отладки `console.log` вместо `alert`. Так можно увидеть содержимое объекта

Comment: пробовал, не помогло.

Comment: а что выводит? `console.info`, как один из вариантов

Answer (score 0):

Попробовать так:

```
socket.onmessage = function(msg)
{
   alert( JSON.stringify(msg) );
}
```